# Insert Separator in glue_data using magrittr

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am building up a simple `INSERT INTO` query from a data frame as with the toy example:

```
library(datasets)
library(magrittr)
library(reprex)
insert_into_01 <-
    "INSERT INTO teams (mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat)\nVALUES"

# The separator does not get inserted at the end of each () line
insert_into_02 <- head(mtcars, 5) %>%
    glue::glue_data("({mpg}, {cyl}, {disp}, \\
                    {hp}, {drat})", .sep = ",")

insert_into_03 <- ";"

qry_create_teams_04 <- stringr::str_c(c(insert_into_01, insert_into_02, 
                                        insert_into_03),
                                      collapse = "\n")

qry_create_teams_04 %>% cat()
#> INSERT INTO teams (mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat)
#> VALUES
#> (21, 6, 160, 110, 3.9)
#> (21, 6, 160, 110, 3.9)
#> (22.8, 4, 108, 93, 3.85)
#> (21.4, 6, 258, 110, 3.08)
#> (18.7, 8, 360, 175, 3.15)
#> ;
```

The problem is that the `.sep` command does not seem to be passed in correctly in the `glue_data` function. The value entries should have a comma `,` after each entry.

EDIT: The expected output is:

```
#> INSERT INTO teams (mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat)
#> VALUES
#> (21, 6, 160, 110, 3.9), #<-- see the comma at the end
#> (21, 6, 160, 110, 3.9), #<-- another comma here
#> (22.8, 4, 108, 93, 3.85),
#> (21.4, 6, 258, 110, 3.08),
#> (18.7, 8, 360, 175, 3.15) # <-- no comma for the last entry
#> ;
```

Could anyone please help assist with the above?

I specifically want to code to use **`tidyverse`** and **`glue`** packages as cleanly as possible to allow for this ideally

Comment: Try `cat(gsub("\\)", "),", qry_create_teams_04), '\n')`

Comment: @akrun - thanks - though this is not what I require. This adds a comma at the end of the INSERT INTO line. Also I specifically want to use the `glue` package and `glue_data` code so that I can extend for further applications

Comment: Not sure if it is a bug or not with `.sep`.  The examples are not using that in the help page

Comment: why not `"({mpg}, {cyl}, {disp}, {hp}, {drat}),"` ? `.sep` has the same purpose as `collapse` in `paste()`, i.e it serves no purpose when there's only one argument like here.

Comment: Why are you creating this string? It would be better (and much safer!) to use an existing function like `DBI::dbWriteTable()`

Comment: @hadley - thanks! I was just experimenting with databases and `R` and thought in this manual way. Your suggestion is great. However, in the above approach, I can separately create a `SQL` table cleanly as ```qry <-
    "CREATE TABLE teams
(mpg numeric, cyl numeric, disp smallint, hp numeric, drat numeric);"

dbSendQuery(con, qry)
```. This gives a lot of flexibility in creating the table and then manually inserting into. Does `dbWriteTable` allow for this level of flexibility? Sorry for the naive questions.

Comment: It is obviously less flexible than creating the SQL yourself, but it avoids generating invalid SQL (which your code will if any of the input contains special characters)

Comment: (If you really want to solve this problem with glue, you are looking for `glue::collapse()` and `glue_data_sql()`)

Comment: @hadley. Many thanks for your patience given my limited experience in `R` and databases. I will aim to use `dbWriteTable` to answer the above rather than `glue`. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

`.sep` is a separator that is applied when you supply multiple arguments. If you need a trailing character, just add it as last argument:

```
glue_data(head(mtcars, 4), "({mpg}, {cyl}, {disp}, {hp}, {drat})", ",")
#> (21, 6, 160, 110, 3.9),
#> (21, 6, 160, 110, 3.9),
#> (22.8, 4, 108, 93, 3.85),
#> (21.4, 6, 258, 110, 3.08),
```

This supposes an empty separator `""` which is the default.

Comment: thanks for this. There is a slight issue namely that the "," gets added for the **last** entry (i.e. after `(21.4, 6, 258, 110, 3.08)`) in your example above` which should not happen for the SQL query. Is there a way to avoid this? I believe typically the `.sep` should handle this. I should have clarified this in my question above.